# Different functionality under one scenario

Tags: jmeter

I want to edit the "Register Form" with 100 users. Out of 100 users, 98 users will click edit and perform some changes and then click save button remaining 2 users will click the edit button and immediately cancel that page.

Answer (score 4):

JMeter comes with [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) therefore you can add 2 Throughput Controllers to your Thread Group and in one specify either 98 total executions for "Save form" scenario or use 98% of app virtual users to do so.

Another Throughput Controller will get remaining 2 executions (or 2% of executions)

[image]

Check out [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information on the concept.